# Which android versions playing html5 videos inline and which in its own native player?

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, smartphone

I need to know if my HTML5 Video in my website will be played inline (inside my html5 page) or if it will be played fullscreen in the native video player.

As far as is know there is no possibility to detect that somehow.

So unfortunately i need to check the userAgent and have to decide it depending on the android version.

Can somebody tell me how each version reacts?
And can it be different on the same android version if the user uses a different browser?